# Transposing div elements using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'll jump to an example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>Transposing div using CSS</title>

        <style>
            div#wrapper {
            }

            div#menu {
                border:blue solid 1px;
            }

            div#main {
                border:red solid 1px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>How do we show the menu div immediately after the content div?</p>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="menu">Menu</div>
            <div id="main">Content</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In a browser, the menu div will come first in the flow. Now let's say that I need to change the layout so that "Menu" **follows** the content div content. How can this be done using CSS only. That means no change to HTML (no user agent detection stuff) and no JavaScript code.

The main CSS technique to position elements is to use the float:right|left attribute. It works well to move elements with respect to their bounding box, but I'm looking at moving an element at the end of its successor element in the normal flow.

And here's the use case. I want a web site to show up optimally on small screen browsers like on an iPhone. The web site currently has the menu at the top and content below, a very common layout but on an iPhone, the real estate is so limited that it would be preferable to have the menu following the main text content.

The solution only has to work with iPhone and Android mobiles ([WebKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit)-based). So no need for taking into account [Internet Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer) hacks and such.

Comment: I'm purely interested in the presentation layer, not the order of elements in the DOM. That can't be changed anyway as I said (no HTML changes). We can take elements out of the normal flow and position them using top, left, bottom, etc with respect to their containing element (position:relative) or the first non static element (position:absolute). I just don't see how we can get two floating elements to swap place in the presentation layer.

Comment: The sample HTML is not well-formed - it is missing the <html> tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your menu has a fixed height (which most likely it does) you could use the same principles as the sticky footer: apply position relative on the wrapper, and a bottom padding of the same height as the menu. In code:

```
div#wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

div#menu {
    border:blue solid 1px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2px; /*to offset the border pxs*/
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;  
}

div#main {
    border:red solid 1px;
}
```

You can view it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/3ZheQ/

Comment: Yes, that works quite nicely. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: I wrote too quickly. It's a good solution but it unfortunately doesn't work if the content div (#main) text changes. In other word, if you put a lorem ipsum paragraph instead of "Content", the text will flow behind and then after the menu div.
To recap, the menu div has fixed height. The main (content) div height varies depending on the text it contains.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following, the content can change it's height, as in http://jsfiddle.net/xxz5G/

Comment: My mistake (it was late at night). Your code is working even with a variable height central div. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this on mobile phones yet, but I often did this on regular sites. I usually did it so that I wrapped both `.menu` and `.menu_section` into the `.header` div. Then you set some basic `margin-top` to the `.menu` div and add `position:relative` to the `.header`. Now header is your last relative for `.menu` and `.menu_section`.

Now just set `position:absolute` to the `.menu_section`, and you can set the top margin to 0. The `.menu` is going to be offset by the top margin while the `.menu_section` will be absolutely positioned at top of header.

If the design requires it, you can solve any overlapping with z-indexes (but you're not working for Internet Explorer oldies anyway, so that probably won't bother you).

Comment: I really don't see what you mean. Could you "rephrase" it in CSS code. See the updated code example I've put above.